# Cronjob for curator

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

I have installed ELK and the latest curator 4.0. I would like to made it regularly run with cronjob in linux.

1. I have installed .curator at the linux home, i.e. `cd~`.
2. I have typed `crontab -e`.
3. I input the following statement `* * * * * /.curator curator action.yml`

Is this setting right? How should I check if it is running or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - For curator installation checkout: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/installation.html

2 - You can edit crontab entries like that. Thats OK.

3 - If you install curator correctly you can run:

```
* * * * * curator /path/to/action/file/action.yml
```

That will run curator every minute with the specified `action.yml` file.

For crontab log checkout: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log

Comment: I have input 20 0 * * * curator .curator/action.yml into the cron job. However, when I check this morning going into the /var/log/cron file, it only displays Jul 29 00:20:01 localhost CROND[35575]: (Administrator) CMD (curator .curator/action.yml). Does that mean it works?

Comment: Yes. Based on your pattern your command should run on 00:20 every day. It seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a path for the log file in the configuration.

logging:
  loglevel: INFO
  logfile: /home/logs/curator.log
  logformat: default